# How can deploy contracts to the blockchain without having a full node?

Tags: mist, contract-deployment

Synchronization Mist is going on for too long, how can I deploy a contract?

Comment: You can do it via MyEtherWallet as well without installing node locally or on your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, use it for deploy contracts:

https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.11+commit.68ef5810.js